# How to update value of a specific key in array of objects in react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, setstate

I'm creating a user role management form like this:

[image: User role management form]

Whenever the user checks or unchecks a permission, I'm trying to put that in the state so that I can send it to my backend server and update the DB.

I'm storing all the rows info in the state in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.users.items){
            this.setState({
                userobj : nextProps.users.items['users']
            });
            const userarr = []
            nextProps.users.items['users'].map((i) => {     

                userarr.push({"employeeid" : i['employeeid'] , "isadmin": i['isadmin'], "isreports" : i['isreports'], "ischarts": i['ischarts'], "ischathistory": i['ischathistory']})            
            });
            this.setState({"list" : userarr});
        }
    }
```

Now the state is:

```
list: Object(4)
    ​​
    0: Object { employeeid: "12345", isadmin: false, isreports: true, …  }
    ​​
    1: Object { employeeid: "12346", isadmin: false, isreports: true, … }
    ​​
    2: Object { employeeid: "12347", isadmin: false, isreports: true, … }
    ​​
    3: {…}
```

There is an `onClick` event for each checkbox:

```
<Table.Td>{rows['isadmin'] ? <Checkbox  id={rows['employeeid']} name="isadmin" defaultChecked onChange={this.handleChange}></Checkbox> : <Checkbox  id={rows['employeeid']} name="isadmin" onChange={this.handleChange}></Checkbox>}</Table.Td>
```

And this is the code for `handleChange`:

```
handleChange(id) {
        const checked = id.target.checked;
        const empid = id.target.id;
        const name = id.target.name;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            list: {
              ...prevState.list,
              [this.getIndex(empid, this.state.list, 'employeeid')]: {
                ...prevState[this.getIndex(empid, this.state.list, 'employeeid')],
                [name] : checked
              },
            }
        }));
    }
```

The result is:

```
list: Object(4)
​​
0: Object { isadmin: true }
​​
1: Object { employeeid: "12346", isadmin: false, isreports: true, … }
​​
2: Object { employeeid: "12347", isadmin: false, isreports: true, … }
​​
3: {…}
```

What I need to achieve is:

```
list: Object(4)
​​
0: Object { employeeid: "12345", isadmin: true, isreports: true, …  }
​​
1: Object { employeeid: "12346", isadmin: false, isreports: true, … }
​​
2: Object { employeeid: "12347", isadmin: false, isreports: true, … }
​​
3: {…}
```

I'm new to React and Redux. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. ☺

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
    this.setState(prevState => ({
            list: {
              ...prevState.list,
              [this.getIndex(empid, this.state.list, 'employeeid')]: {
                ...prevState[this.getIndex(empid, this.state.list, 'employeeid')],
                [name] : checked
              },
            }
        }));
```

With this:

```
    this.setState(prevState => ({
            list: {
              ...prevState.list,
              [this.getIndex(empid, this.state.list, 'employeeid')]: {
                ...prevState.list[this.getIndex(empid, this.state.list, 'employeeid')],
                [name] : checked
              },
            }
        }));
```

Comment: for the first time it gave me the desired result, when i uncheck the same checkbox, it is adding another object with index -1 and changing it instead of the actual object

Answer (score 0):

try updating your handleChange method to this

```
    handleChange(id) {
  const checked = id.target.checked;
  const empid = id.target.id;
  const name = id.target.name;

  this.setState(prevState => ({
      let list = prevState.list
      let user = prevState.list.filter(user => user.employeeid == id)
      const userIndex = prevState.list.indexOf(user)
      user = {
        ...user,
        isadmin: true
      }

      list.splice(userIndex, 1)       //remove the old user
      list.splice(userIndex, 0, user) //put the updated user at same index

      this.setState({list})
  }));
}
```